# Raspberry Pi 3 WiFi Driver

Tags: pi-3

What is the driver for the built in WiFi adapter on RPI 3? I am trying to make my pi a Wifi hotspot and I need the driver name.

Comment: Use create_ap instead,which is simple to use and does not need driver name.It is available on github

Answer (score 6):

The driver is called `brcmfmac` for the Broadcom wifi hardware.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you are using Raspbian, it gets automatically loaded.

If you are not using Raspbian, just boot it temporarily, note the drivers that it loads, and then use that list to get it working with the distribution you are using.